# How to copy specific columns for rows where there is a "yes" in a particular column

Tags: excel, vba

Objective:

There is data stored in sheet "Risk Partner Data" in a table called "RPdata". In the table there is a column called "AICOW" which bears two results, yes or no.

In a second sheet called "Calc Data", I would like to build a macro that starts at after the last filled cell (but ignores a cell that is empty in between data), and for every row that has a "yes" result in AICOW, it copies into row A the corresponding [RPdata@Parish].

The result I am after is that at the end of Column A, the macro will add the parish name for only the parishes with AICOW (yes) and not any others.

I have attempted but my code is not working and I'm not sure its even right

```
Set Source = Sheet("Risk Partner Data")
Set c.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=if("RPdata[@[AICOW]]"=""Yes"","Yes",0)
Set Target = [RPdata@Parish]
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.For each c in source.range(RPdata[@AICOW])
If c = "yes" Then
Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(a)
a = a + 1
End If
End c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping, consider filtering and copying the visible cells from the "Parish" column in one go.

Also, consider using the built-in `ListObject` and `ListColumn` objects.

```
Sub CopyParishes()
    Dim riskPartnerDataTbl As ListObject
    Dim parishCol As ListColumn, AICOWcol As ListColumn
    Dim copyRng As Range

    Set riskPartnerDataTbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Risk Partner Data").ListObjects("RPdata")
    With riskPartnerDataTbl
        Set parishCol = .ListColumns("Parish")
        Set AICOWcol = .ListColumns("AICOW")
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=AICOWcol.Index, Criteria1:="Yes"
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Set copyRng = parishCol.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not copyRng Is Nothing Then
        copyRng.Copy

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calc Data")
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    riskPartnerDataTbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=AICOWcol.Index
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi BigBen, thank you! However would this work if I had not only the Parish to copy, but some other columns as well and a calculation to add for each column result? Thank you heaps!

Comment: So you're not copying the entire row, but just from certain columns? Are those columns all side by side? What is the calculation - a formula?

Comment: Hi BigBen, yes not the entire row, only certain columns and they are not side by side. E.g. Column A, D, K, & L to go to A, B, D, E, with C simply copying "AICOW". Calculation is to split a fee in sheet "Rating Table" equally amongst all AICOW "yes" parishes.

Comment: What are the headers in columns A, D, K, and L?

Comment: Also what version of Excel are you using? Because there may be a much simpler way to do this.

Comment: Excel 2010. And headers are as follows: RPdata@Property Identifier, RPdata@Parish Code, RPdata@Building ID 1, RPdata@Address 1

Comment: Hmm - if you have Office 2010 Professional Plus with Software Assurance, you could use Power Query. Otherwise I can tweak the approach - i.e. still filter, but then copy the visible cells from each of those columns.